# Power Apps form embedded in Power BI to update Sharepoint List

Tags: list, powerapp, powerbi

I created a SharePoint Online list that tracks cases. Users review and update cases through a Power Apps form on the site. I also have a Power BI visualization that is querying the SharePoint list to display graphs. Is there a way to put the existing Power Apps form into the Power BI so that users can update the cases from there? I want users to be able to update the Power Apps form in the Power BI and have those updates reflected in the SharePoint Online list.

Answer (score 1):

I think for your requirement you can use ***PowerApps custom visual for Power BI***.
Please refer below link:

1. [PowerApps custom visual for Power BI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/powerapps-custom-visual)
2. [Sample video for overview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-CjGKoXem0I&feature=youtu.be)